# Diacritics and Ashanti/Twi alphabet?

Tags: alphabets, african-languages, diacritics

*[Ashanti Proverbs (The Primitive Ethics Of A Savage People)](https://archive.org/details/ashantiproverbs00chrigoog)*, by Robert Sutherland Rattray, 1916, uses the following notation :

[image: excerpt of the book]

I read that Ashanti people speak Twi, yet the Twi alphabet [does not seem](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/twi.htm) to have such diacritics as the ones used in the sentence above.

Is this alphabet obsolete (the book is one century old, and it writes Twi with a caron on the 'w'), and if so how would one write this sentence nowadays ?

### Update

Thanks to user6726's answer and further investigation, I believe the modern spelling must be close to `ɔketew nwe mako na fifiri mfi atwerorɔ`.

Notes :

- I found a few Twi/Akan-English dictionaries online, which proved helpful : [J.G. Christaller's very old one](https://archive.org/stream/adictonaryengli00lochgoog), [kasahorow.org](http://ak.kasahorow.org/app/d), [twi.bb](http://www.twi.bb/), [enacademic.com](http://twi_english.enacademic.com/).
- `nwe` and `mfi` don't appear directly in dictionaries because the `n-` and `m-` are negation prefixes : entries are for `we` ("chew") and `fi` ("from").
- `atwerorɔ` does not appear either, I guess because it's a rare (or extinguished ?) word : the original source mentions it's a kind of frog, not the common word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text uses the old (obsolete) orthography developed by J.G. Christaller about 150 years ago. *(t)w̌* represents labio-palatalization, IPA [tɕɥ], which is now simply *tw* (it's predictable, but was in the old spelling because it's phonetically noteworthy). Akan vowels are a bit challenging since it sounds like they have 3 kinds of mid vowels (*ɛ e ɪ* but *ɪ* sounds like *e*, but not the same as *e*). Underscore on *e,o* means [ɛ ɔ], and dots under a vowel means "+ATR". N-dot is [ŋ], and acute accent indicates tone. Diacritics were employed sporadically in the old days (and diacritics are eschewed in the modern world). Can't help with modern spelling.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Is Christaller's alphabet the same as the [Gold Coast Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Coast_alphabet) ?

Comment: (The WP table seems to contradict [Christaller's definitions](https://archive.org/details/adictonaryengli00lochgoog), but it could be due to mistakes from the WP editor…)

Comment: That's a bit off-topic, but I'm struggling to compute an IPA representation of this sentence ; if by any chance you can help I'd be very grateful.